# python -m pip install urllib having systax error while installation of this module

Tags: module, syntax-error, token, python-3.5, failed-installation

[here see what happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLpDh.jpg)
when I run the above command cmd I get an error while installing. As you can see in the above image. 
s.connect((base64.b64decode(rip),17620)
I get syntax error: invalid token in line 191

and it is also giving me problems on some other modules also.
s.connect((base64.b64decode(rip),17620)
I get syntax error: invalid token in line 191

Comment: i have posted an image i hope you can see it

Answer (score 0):

(I ran into this myself using jupyter notebook)

As you are using python 3 you don't need to install URL lib as it is part of core https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Lib/urllib/

It's submodules are restructured so you need to change python 2 code like

```
import urllib
...
urllib.urlopen
```

into

```
import urllib.request
...
urllib.request.urlopen
```